# Make individual attachments private?

Tags: attachments

Is there any way to make individual attachments private similar to how a post can be made private? I've looked through various plugins but none really seem to do the job. They usually make all attachments private which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put a Custom Field to the attachments and filter from there.
http://wpengineer.com/2076/add-custom-field-attachment-in-wordpress/